# Table Join issue

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join

Right now I've got a `Main` table in which I am uploading data. Because the `Main` table has many different duplicates, I Append various data out of the `Main` table into other tables such as, username, phone number, and locations in order to keep things optimized. Once I have everything stripped down from the `Main` table, I then append what's left into a final optimized `Main` table. Before this happens though, I run a select query joining all the stripped tables with the original `Main` table in order to connect the IDs from each table, with the correct data. For example:

```
Original Main Table
--Name---------Number------Due Date-------Location-------Charges Monthly-----Charges Total--
John Smith     111-1111     4/3           Chicago         234.56             500.23
Todd Jones     222-2222     4/3           New York        174.34             323.56
John Smith     111-1111     4/3           Chicago         274.56             670.23
Bill James     333-3333     4/3           Orlando         100.00             100.00
```

This gets split into 3 tables (name, number, location) and then there is a date table with all the dates for the year:

```
 Name Table                Number Table            Location Table        Due Date Table
--ID---Name------         -ID--Number---------     ---ID---Location----   --Date---
  1    John Smith          1 111-1111                  1    Chicago          4/1
  2    Todd Jones          2 222-2222                  2    New York         4/2
  3    Bill James          3 333-3333                  3    Orlando          4/3
```

Before The Original table gets stripped, I run a select query that grabs the ID from the 3 new tables, and joins them based on the connection they have with the original `Main` table.

```
     Select Output
 --Name ID----Number ID---Location ID---Due Date--
    1          1              1          4/3
    2          2              2          4/3
    1          1              1          4/3
    3          3              3          4/3
```

My issue comes when I need to introduce a new table that isn't able to be tied into the Original Main Table. I have an inventory table that, much like the original `Main` table, has duplicates and needs to be optimized. I do this by creating a secondary table that takes all the duplicated devices out and put them in their own table, and then strips the username and number out and puts them into their tables. I would like to add the IDs from this new device table into the select output that I have above. Resulting in:

```
     Select Output
 --Name ID----Number ID---Location ID---Due Date--Device ID---
    1          1              1          4/3        1
    2          2              2          4/3        1
    1          1              1          4/3        2
    3          3              3          4/3        1
```

Unlike the previous tables, the device table has no relationship to the original`Main` Table, which is what is causing me so much headache. I can't seem to find a way to make this happen...is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: It would help if you can narrow down your question (it looks like a project development spec). In case you want to remove duplicates from the table, there is an option to use SELECT DISTINCT in query, which may help. Regards,

Comment: The issue is I can't join the device table with the select query that outputs the rest of the IDs because there is no relationship between device and the original `main` table.

Comment: As I already stated, please narrow down the scope of your question: is this issue caused by removing duplicates, or there is another one, regardless of duplicates (like adding foreign keys in table relationship, etc.)? Thanks and regards,

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you want. You have already pointed out that the issue is that there is no relation between the tables. If your goal is to display both tables in a results table, you could union the two tables together. You should be a little more specific.

Comment: Duplicates really have nothing to do with it, I simply mentioned it for details sake. I don't know how to narrow the question down any further. the `device` table and the `main` table need to be joined, but I have been unable to join them because of the lack of a relationship. Sorry for so much detail(that may or may not be useful), I was told I didn't give enough detail in a previous question.

Comment: Also, when designing a database schema, it is best to normalize it then rather than after there is data in the tables.

Comment: @czifro I was trying to see if there was a way to bring the 2 tables together since there wasn't a relationship. I was unable to find a way to join tables that had no relationship, but now that you mention the union, I will see if that works.

Comment: @FatCat, I have posted an answer illustrating a union.

Comment: You are unclear. "Optimize", "stripped down", "split", "connect", "grab", "connection they have", "add the IDs" and "has no relationship" don't mean anything. (Although with your examples we can make some guesses.) You are using words that seem to you to be consistent with what you are doing but since we don't know what you are doing they don't communicate it. Use technical terms about table parts and operations. Explain what you are doing to what parts under what conditions. [Work through a full example from input to output.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just wondering... are the last paragraphs of my answer any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any two tables can be joined. A table represents an application relationship. In some versions (not the original) of Entity-Relationship Modelling (notice that the "R" in E-R stands for "(application) relationship"!) a foreign key is sometimes called a "relationship". You do not need other tables or FKs to join any two tables.

Explain, in terms of its column names and the values for those names, exactly when a row should turn up in the result. Maybe you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM the stripped-and-ID'd version of the Original AS o
JOIN the stripped-and-ID'd version of the Device AS d
USING NameID, NumberID, LocationID and DueDate
```

Ie

```
SELECT *
FROM the stripped-and-ID'd version of the Original AS o
JOIN the stripped-and-ID'd version of the Device AS d
ON o.NameID=d.NameId AND o.NumberID=d.NumberID
   AND o.LocationID=d.LocationID AND o.DueDateID=d.DueDate.
```

Suppose *p*(*a*,...) is some statement parameterized by *a*,... .

If o holds the rows where o(NameID,NumberID,LocationID,DueDate) and d holds the rows where d(NameID,NumberID,LocationID,DueDate,DeviceID) then the above holds the rows where o(NameID, NumberID, LocationID, DueDate) AND d(NameID,NumberID,LocationID,DueDate,DeviceID). But you really have not explained what rows you want.

Comment: I think you missed the point of his question, although it was not clearly stated. He wants to take the union of two unrelated tables. He clearly understands how to join tables together based on a relationship.

Comment: I really can't make much of sense of his question. I agree he's "appending" (unioning) in there somewhere. I think the OP clearly *doesn't* understand JOIN. One doesn't join via (or on) a relationship (whatever that means); one can join on a condition. "I would like to add the IDs from this new device table into the select output that I have above" and the subsequent example suggests the join in my answer. But there are probably further constraints ("relationships"), tables and/or conditions involved.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "join" tables that have no relation is by unioning them together:

```
select attribute1, attribute2, ... , attributeN
from table1
where <predicate>
union       // or union all
select attribute1, attribute2, ... , attributeN
from table2
where <predicate>
```

the where clauses are obviously optional

**EDIT**

optionally you could join the tables together by stating `ON true` which will act like a cross product